# Mono not download avalibal for ubuntu20.04

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I do not edit scrip with mono.
I use unity c# script for debugging and autocomplete in MonoDevelop...
so we need support for ubuntu 20.04 MonoDevelop ...

Comment: Unity does not use MonoDevelop any longer. You should move to things like JetBrains Rider.

Comment: On Linux, you can use Visual Studio Code or JetBrains Rider, this change was made back in 2018 (Unity 2018.1) On Mac/Windows, Visual Studio is installed/used by 
 Unity (but you can use VSC or Rider is needed)

Comment: thanks for replay but I need free with open source IDE.